# Stop shaking in CSS animation

Tags: css, css-animations

So I'm making a tic tac toe game right now and I'm trying to add in an animation for a line that shows who won. When the player wins by getting 3 horizontal things then the animation works perfectly but when they win vertically then there's a slight shake on it. Is there any way I can remove this?

Here is the CSS for the line:

```css
@keyframes grow-left {
    0% {
        width: 0;
    }

    100% {
        width: 1;
    }
}

.winLine {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300%;
    height: var(--borderThickness);
    background-color: var(--textColor);
    border-radius: 1rem;
    transform-origin: center;
    z-index: 2;
    animation: grow-left 1s ease-in-out 0s;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

To view the website and see what I'm talking about it's live on GitHub at this link https://bartycoding.github.io/Tic-tac-toe/

Comment: Chrome did not appear to exhibit "a slight shake" after a vertical win. Is this a browser specific problem?

Comment: After further review, a very slight shake could be seen after a vertical win with Chrome. The results could vary with different graphics processors on the systems running this CSS animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually fixed this by having the rotation as a global css variable and then changing that variable from javascript so the css looks like this:

```css
@keyframes grow-left {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(var(--winLineRotation)) scaleX(0);
    }

    100% {
        transform: rotate(var(--winLineRotation)) scaleX(100%);
    }
}

.winLine {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300%;
    height: var(--borderThickness);
    background-color: var(--textColor);
    border-radius: 1rem;
    transform-origin: center;
    z-index: 2;
    animation: grow-left 1s ease-in-out 0s;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotate(var(--winLineRotation));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating another div that increases the height instead of using the transform: rotate(90deg);

Comment: I could do that but then the code would get messy as I would need different styles for the horizontal, vertical, and slanted ones and different animations which is something I would preferably like to avoid

Answer (score 0):

You could try with `transform: scale()`:

```
@keyframes grow-left {
    0% {
        transform: scale(0,1);
    }

    100% {
        transform: scale(1,1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I did think of doing that but that would interfere with the transform: rotate(90deg) and wouldn't apply any rotation

Comment: Yo can do `transform: scale(0,1) rotate(90deg);`.

Comment: The rotation is applied as an inline style using javascript so I can't do that as the rotation will change

Answer (score 0):

To prevent that little shake at the end of animations, you need to use :  `backface-visibility:hidden;` to the class of the element that you've defined animation for.

```
@keyframes grow-left {
    0% {
        width: 0;
    }

    100% {
        width: 1;
    }
}

.winLine {
    /* Try this */
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    width: 300%;
    height: var(--borderThickness);
    background-color: var(--textColor);
    border-radius: 1rem;
    transform-origin: center;
    z-index: 2;
    animation: grow-left 1s ease-in-out 0s;
    opacity: 1;
}
```